# What is the eigenvalue of an arbitrary state?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

I found this questions [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17562/expectation-value-of-a-quantum-circuit) assumes that eigenvalue of $|0001\rangle$ is $-1$. Can someone please explain how does this work for this example? How does it work in general for any state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An eigenvalue is measured relative to a particular operator/matrix. For example, in the linked question, it was considering the operator $Z\otimes Z\otimes Z\otimes Z$.

Recall that for any operator/matrix $M$, a state $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ if and only if it can be written as
$$
M|\psi\rangle=\lambda|\psi\rangle.
$$
So, in the present case, you simply need to evaluate
$$
Z\otimes Z\otimes Z\otimes Z|0001\rangle=(Z|0\rangle)\otimes (Z|0\rangle)\otimes (Z|0\rangle)\otimes (Z|1\rangle).
$$
Using the definition of $Z$ that $Z|0\rangle=|0\rangle$ and $Z|1\rangle=-|1\rangle$, you'll find
$$
Z\otimes Z\otimes Z\otimes Z|0001\rangle=-|0001\rangle,
$$
and hence it is an eigenvector with eigenvalue -1.

Note that without a matrix, you cannot say anything. Even with a matrix, most of the time, a given state will not be an eigenvector. It is a very specific property.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalues and eigenstates are properties of operators.

For an operator $A$, its eigenstates are the states $x$ that imply that $Ax=\lambda x$

So all $x$ that imply this for a given $x$ is the eigenstates of $A$, and its eigenvalue is the scalar $\lambda$ that is coming out of $Ax$.

In your case there was some operator, the $x$ was $|0001\rangle$, and $\lambda$ the eigenvalue was $-1.$